# Timeoutexception when importing Csv file into datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, google-cloud-datastore

This application works perfectly locally but when i try it on the server i get a timeoutexception. The file i'm trying to import is utf-8 and contains icelandic characters(á, ú, í, æ, é, ð, ö)

heres the code:
def get(self):

```
    site = "order"

    scripts = """
        <script>

            $('#csv').ajaxForm({
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#update').html("Loading...");
                },
                complete: function(data) {
                    $('#update').html(data.responseText);
                }
            });
        </script>
    """

    content = """
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <div class="large-12 columns" id="update">
                <form id="csv" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="import">
                    <select name="db">
                        <option value="users">Users</option>
                        <option value="machines">Machines</option>
                        <option value="company">Company</option>

                        <option value="process">Order</option>
                        <option value="status">Status</option>
                        <option value="part">Part</option>

                        <option value="machineType">Machine Type</option>
                    <select>
                    <input name="file" type="file">
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="button">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    """

    template_values = {
        'site': site,
        'scripts': scripts,
        'content': content,
    }


    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('main.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

def post(self):

    out = """
        <div style='background: green; border: 1px solid green; border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 3px;  padding: 5px;'>
            {{import}} rows important <a style="float:right;  color:white;">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div style='border: 1px solid gray; padding: 5px;'>
    """

    file = self.request.get('file')

    reader = file.decode('utf-8').split('\n')

    database = self.request.get('db')

    out += import_excel.bulkImport(reader, database)

    self.response.write(out)

@staticmethod
def bulkImport(reader, database):

    rows = 0
    out = ""

    if database == "users":
        for row in reader:
            rows += 1

            tiles = row.split(';')

            x = users(idno = tiles[0],
                  company = tiles[1],
                  firstname = tiles[2],
                  lastname = tiles[3],
                  phone = tiles[4],
                  fax = tiles[5],
                  email = tiles[6],
                  comments = tiles[7])
            x.put()

            out += "Row imported [" + tiles[0] + ", "  + tiles[1] + ", "  + tiles[2] + ", "  + tiles[3] + ", "  + tiles[4] + ", "  + tiles[5] + ", "  + tiles[6] + ", "  + tiles[7] + "]</br>" 
    elif database == "machines":
        for row in reader:
            rows += 1

            tiles = row.split(';') 

            x = machines(ID = tiles[0],
                  brand = tiles[1],
                  type = tiles[2],
                  year = tiles[3],
                  SN = tiles[4],
                  owner = tiles[5],
                  comments = tiles[6])

            x.put()

            out += "Row imported [" + tiles[0] + ", "  + tiles[1] + ", "  + tiles[2] + ", "  + tiles[3] + ", "  + tiles[4] + ", "  + tiles[5] + ", "  + tiles[6] + "]</br>" 
    elif database == "companies":
        for row in reader:
            rows += 1

            tiles = row.split(';') 

            x = company(ID = tiles[0],
                  name = tiles[1],
                  street = tiles[2],
                  zip = tiles[3],
                  city = tiles[4],
                  country = tiles[5],
                  phone = tiles[6],
                  fax = tiles[7],
                  email = tiles[8],
                  comments = tiles[9])
            x.put()

            out += "Row imported [" + tiles[0] + ", "  + tiles[1] + ", "  + tiles[2] + ", "  + tiles[3] + ", "  + tiles[4] + ", "  + tiles[5] + ", "  + tiles[6] + ", "  + tiles[7] + ", " + tiles[8] + ", " + tiles[9] + "]</br>" 
    elif database == "process":
        for row in reader:
            rows += 1

            tiles = row.split(';') 

            x = process(ID = tiles[0],
                  company = tiles[1],
                  contact = tiles[2],
                  machine = tiles[3],
                  status = tiles[4],
                  comments = tiles[5])
            x.put()

            out += "Row imported [" + tiles[0] + ", "  + tiles[1] + ", "  + tiles[2] + ", "  + tiles[3] + ", "  + tiles[4] + ", "  + tiles[5] + "]</br>"
    elif database == "part":
        for row in reader:
            rows += 1

            tiles = row.split(';') 

            x = part(ID = tiles[0],
              no = tiles[1],
              name = tiles[2],
              price = int(tiles[3]),
              company = tiles[4],
              comments = tiles[5])
            x.put()

            out += "Row imported [" + tiles[0] + ", "  + tiles[1] + ", "  + tiles[2] + ", "  + tiles[3] + ", "  + tiles[4] + ", "  + tiles[5] + "]</br>"
    elif database == "machineType":

        for row in reader:
            rows += 1

            tiles = row.replace('&comma', ',').split(';')

            x = machineType(Description = tiles[0],
              ID = tiles[1],
              Brand = tiles[2],
              Type = tiles[3])
            x.put()

            out += "Row imported [" + tiles[0] + ", "  + tiles[1] + ", "  + tiles[2] + ", "  + tiles[3] + "]</br>" 

    out += "</div>"
    out = out.replace("{{import}}", str(rows))
    return out
```

Comment: You have a limit of 60 secs for front facing requests.  Use a task to do the processing, and make sure your instances aren't starting when you try to process the CSV.

Comment: @Tim Hoffman But can you return information when a task is done?

Comment: No, rather you store that information somewhere and then the client polls for it at regular intervals until the job is complete.